# Usage of List.of() in visitor Pattern

Tags: java, list, visitor-pattern

I was going through the Visitor Pattern example from Wikipedia and there is a small piece of code as an example. 
You can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Sources).

If you scroll through the Java example section, the constructor of the `Car()` uses something called `List.of()`.

As per the oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E-), List.of() creates an immutable list. The same piece of code does not seem to work in my personal IntelliJ workspace and there is no recognition of `List.of()`. 
Although, if I could replace it with a mutable list - something like -

```
this.elements = new ArrayList<CarElement>();
this.elements.add(new Wheel("front left"));
this.elements.add(new Wheel("front right"));
this.elements.add(new Wheel("back left"));
this.elements.add(new Wheel("back right"));
this.elements.add(new Body());
this.elements.add(new Engine());
```

I could get the same output. Is there something wrong I am doing?
Has it got anything to do with my JDK version? My JDK version is 1.8.0_45.

Comment: You are looking at the Java 9 documentation. `List.of` does not exist in Java 8. That's what "Since: 9" means.

Comment: For future reference, you can look at the bottom of method's section in the documentation, where it says `Since`. That number under the word `Since` indicates what JDK version the method was added in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [`List::of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) was introduced in JDK 9. Since you are compiling on JDK 8, this will not work.

> **Type Parameters:**
>   `E` - the List's element type
>   **Parameters:**
>   elements - the elements to be contained in the list
>   **Returns:**
>   a List containing the specified elements
>   **Throws:**
>   `NullPointerException` - if an element is null or if the array is null
>   **Since:**
>   9

Notice at the bottom of the docs they have `Since: <version>`. This will tell you which version the method was added in